# How do I use a socket on multiple viewcontrollers? swift-socket.io

Tags: swift, sockets, connection

i want create 1 connection And use it on multiple viewcontrollers without creating a new connection

this is my code for connection :

```
let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "https://mr-fast.liara.run")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
var socket : SocketIOClient!
socket = manager.defaultSocket
socket.connect()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Singleton pattern** for this:

```
class SocketHandler {
    private init(){}
    static let shared = SocketHandler()

    private let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "https://mr-fast.liara.run")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
    private(set) lazy var socket = manager.defaultSocket
}
```

Now you can access it from anywhere like:

```
SocketHandler.shared.socket.connect()
```

<sub>Note that this is just an example, you may want to use different names or use initializer to assign values to the variables.</sub>

Comment: Can I use the same singleton when its have more than one namespace with different params ...

Comment: I'm not sure about your question @WahabKhanJadon

Comment: namespace means different endpoints and connection parameters... we create the instance in the beginning... but what if we want to change the endpoint and connection parameters run time... I believe we just need to update endpoint and params and then need to reconnect again...

Comment: I believe we can not discuss this in the comments. You can ask a question and link me here. So I can try to examine your use case and explain it in detail @WahabKhanJadon